# Intel Graphics drivers help please!

Tags: intel-graphics

I need to install the Graphics Driver in my Ubuntu 16.04 but when I try to install the Intel Graphics updater I get > This package is uninstallable Dependency is not satisfiable: libpackagekit-glib2-18.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the Intel Graphics Updater did you download? There are two most recent; [v2.0.4](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.4) and [v2.0.2](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.2). You want to be using v2.0.2 for Ubuntu 16.04, so if you have downloaded v2.0.4 that may be your issue.

v2.0.4 has been compiled for Ubuntu 16.10 whereas v2.0.2 has been compiled for Ubuntu 16.04. [16.04 does not have the libpackagekit-glib2-18 package in its repositories,](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpackagekit-glib2-18) so v2.0.2 is the latest supported version for 16.04.

Comment: Yes, i am running v.2.0.2 but i still get the same error, and btw if you install intel graphics does your ingame fps increase?

Comment: How are you installing the tool? Can you try and run it with `sudo dpkg -i intel-graphics-update-tool_2.0.2_amd64.deb` from a terminal and update your original post with the output?

Regarding an improvement in ingame FPS, yes - you will get better performance with th newer Intel drivers. However, how much of a performance increase will vary from game to game and between Intel graphics chipsets.

Comment: You really helped me a lot Thank you so Much <3

Comment: No problem :) If your problem is now solved,I would really appreciate it if you could mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: But now i have some other problems, it asked me to reboot the pc to install the changes.. and now when i rebot it shows some error and i cant see my mouse in desktop and i cant use the keyboard..

Comment: Clearin orphaned inode 26615 etc.. i get this error why trying to boot it.. i cant see my mouse or the keyboard.

Comment: That message is a warning, not an error - it shouldn't stop you from booting into your desktop environment by itself.

As the original issue about the Intel driver update tool dependencies has now been resolved, I recommend you ask a new question with all the information you can so we can better help. The danger with continuing troubleshooting in this comments thread is information is likely to get lost or be difficult for other community members to get involved.